# Magento2.2.2: UI Component Grid Filter Issue

Tags: grid, uicomponent, magento2.2.2

In my **custom module**, my **Grid Records** are **deleting perfect without applying filter**. When i **apply filter on grid records** and **try to delete only filtered records**, it not only delete filtered records but other records also gets deleted and grid gets empty.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml;
use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class AbstractMassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

const REDIRECT_URL = '*/*/';

protected $collection = 'Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection';

protected $model = 'Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel';
protected $cat = false;

/**
 * Execute action
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException|\Exception
 */
public function execute()
{

    $selected = $this->getRequest()->getParam('selected');
    $excluded = $this->getRequest()->getParam('excluded');

    try {
        if (isset($excluded)) {
            if (!empty($excluded) && is_array($excluded)) {
                $this->excludedDelete($excluded);
            } else {
                $this->deleteAll();
            }
        } elseif (!empty($selected)) {
            $this->selectedDelete($selected);
        } else {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Please select item(s).'));
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    }


    $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    return $resultRedirect->setPath(static::REDIRECT_URL);
}

/**
 * Delete all
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
protected function deleteAll()
{
    /** @var AbstractCollection $collection */
    $collection = $this->_objectManager->get($this->collection);
    $this->delete($collection, true);
}

/**
 * Delete all but the not selected
 *
 * @param array $excluded
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
protected function excludedDelete(array $excluded)
{
    /** @var AbstractCollection $collection */
    $collection = $this->_objectManager->get($this->collection);
    $collection->addFieldToFilter(static::ID_FIELD, ['nin' => $excluded]);
    $this->delete($collection);
}

/**
 * Delete selected items
 *
 * @param array $selected
 * @return void
 * @throws \Exception
 */
protected function selectedDelete(array $selected)
{
    /** @var AbstractCollection $collection */
    $collection = $this->_objectManager->get($this->collection);
    $collection->addFieldToFilter(static::ID_FIELD, ['in' => $selected]);
    $this->delete($collection);
}

/**
 * Delete collection items
 *
 * @param AbstractCollection $collection
 * @return int
 */
protected function delete(AbstractCollection $collection, $all = false)
{
    $count = 0;
    if ($all) {
        $count = $collection->getSize();

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $item->delete();
        }
    }
    foreach ($collection->getAllIds() as $id) {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $model */
        if ($this->cat) {
            $msg = $this->_objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Productcats')->deleteCategory($id);
        } else {
            $msg = null;
        }
        if ($msg != null) {
            $this->messageManager->addError($msg);
            return;
        } else {
            $model = $this->_objectManager->get($this->model);
            $model->load($id);
            $model->delete();
            ++$count;
        }
    }
    $this->setSuccessMessage($count);
    return $count;
}

/**
 * Set error messages
 *
 * @param int $count
 * @return void
 */
protected function setSuccessMessage($count)
{
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $count));
}

protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) you should directly address the ObjectManager, you should create a __construct and use direct injection.  Here's an example where I'm injecting RuleFactory into one of my controller actions.

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
    JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
    Registry $registry,
    ManagerInterface $messageManager,
    RuleFactory $ruleFactory
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
    $this->_ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;

    parent::__construct($context);

    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
    $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
}
```

2) Use the PHP *use* statement to shorted very long path names and make code readable and easier to maintain.

3) Look at the new ui_component methods for MassAction, they don't use the concept of passing an array of IDS back to the controller action.

Here's a [link](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-add-mass-action-in-admin-grid-in-magento-2/) to a good example